# Laravel append attribute giving out of memory errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I am trying to append the product price  attribute to the product model, but its end up giving out of memory error when i am printing it. 
And when i do `dd` on the response it give me some query builder error.
Can anyone please help me out?

My database and models are as follows:

I have three table `products`, `product_price` & `weight_units`.
In the `[![product_price][1]][1]` table i have `product_id , price, weight, weight_unit_id`  and in `weight_units` i have `unit`.

**My product_price model**

```
 public function weightUnit()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\WeightUnit');
    }
```

**My product model**

```
protected $appends = ['product_price'];

 public function price(){
       return $this->hasMany(ProductPrice::class);
    }
 public function getProductPriceAttribute(){
        return $this->price()->with('weightUnit:id,unit');
    }
```

**My controller**

```
$data=   Product::take(2)->get();
        echo '<pre>';
        dd($data->toArray());
```

When i try to print it it gives out of memory error, and when i do dd i get to see what is in the screenshot.

Comment: `productPrice` attribute gives you a Query Builder instance. You don't want a string / integer instead?

Comment: @Marwelln yes i want the value only, but i am not sure why its giving me query builder instance. This suppose not to happen

Answer (score 0):

`$this->price()` only gives you a query builder instance, replace it with `$this->price`.
Then replace `->with(` with `->load(`:

```
return $this->price->load('weightUnit:id,unit');
```

Eager loading doesn't make a lot of sense there, you should move it to `price()`:

```
return $this->hasMany(ProductPrice::class)->with('weightUnit:id,unit');
```